# Selecting data from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table which has an ID column and some other columns. The second table has also ID column. Now I want to insert into second table rows from first table, but only those that don't appear in it already. I want the second table to be "a sum" of both, but without duplicates.

The first one is `labels` and the second is `tags`. Both has `label` column.
I want to insert 
`labels.label, "", "", "", "N", "N/A"`
into tags for all labels found in `labels` table but not in `tags`, because labels in tags are already some data filled in.

I've tried

```
INSERT INTO tags SELECT labels.label, "", "", "", "N", "N/A" FROM labels, tags
WHERE labels.label != tags.label
```

but I'm getting a lot of duplicates. The same applies for

```
INSERT INTO tags SELECT labels.label, "", "", "", "N", "N/A" FROM labels
JOIN tags ON labels.label != tags.label
```

Maybe I just don't get an idea, because I'm quite new into SQL.

How can I achieve that? I'm using SQLite with Python.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

You could start here

```
insert into t2 (col1, col2 ...)
select colx, coly, ... from t1
where t1.ID not in
(select ID from t2)
)
```

The insert into syntax assumes that the second table (t2) already exists.  If you wanted to create the new table, you'd select col1, col2 ... into NewTable.

EDIT: Changed "exists" to "in" b/c SQL Lite prefers "in".

Comment: but, yes, the second table do exist!